# Non copyable image in PDF

Tags: graphics

When an image is inserted in a pdf with the graphicx package, a right click on the image in the output gives the possibility to copy the image. My question is how can one block this possibility?

I guess there is an option in the graphicx package to do so, but I couldn't find it in the package manual (I find this manual not very helpful, especially for the neophyte).

As requested, here is a Minimal Example (where image is any image .jpg):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

   \begin{center} 
    \includegraphics{image}
   \end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE to start with, so that users can start searching a solution (if there is such at all). To which manual do you refer?

Comment: Just tried with package `accsupp` and it doesn't work, there is still a "copy" menu (both in Acroread 9 and Evince). I presume it is not not possible. Besides, anyone can grab a screenshot of the image. (This question applies to raster images anyway).

Comment: I think this is a feature of the `.pdf` file format itself and not directly connected to TeX. Copying content out of the file can be prohibited using `pdftk` for example, but for the whole file, not for just parts of it. I believe, that it is not possible to select which content might be copyable.

Comment: If possible you trace the picture to create vector graphics, which cannot be "copied" by just right clicking. They can still be extracted with, e.g. Inkscape.

Comment: When you can see an image you always can copy it using print screen, for example.

Comment: Or just taking a snap shot of the screen.

Comment: Thank you all for comments. However, in this pdf: http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap12.pdf the figures (for exemple, the regions in the plane) cannot be copied. 

Is it because this is not inserted images, but figures drawn with Latex commands? In the second case, which package has been used? I am sorry if the answer to this last question is obvious, but I am very bad at inserting documents in Latex, and have no knowledge in drawing packages.

Comment: I think it is very important to mention here that all this is an Acrobat-only thing and by no means any kind of effective copy protection! With any PDFKit-based Mac-Viewer, for instance, (Slim, Preview, ...) I can easily select any rectangular region from the PDF and "copy" it into a new PDF (as vector image). Please make this clear in your question that you want to disable the "Copy" drop-down menu in Acrobat and are not looking for a general copy protection (which doesn't exist).

Comment: (+1) for @Daniel's comment. Any answer will work for Adobe-software at best. (And I would not really like to guarantee anything in that case.) Since everyone has easy access to software where the solution won't work, I think, frankly, you are whistling in the wind. The only possible effect will be to disadvantage Windows users who know very little about software. (I don't mean Windows users know very little. I mean those who are both Windows users and who know little. On other platforms, the default PDF viewer won't be from Adobe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `clip=true` option, you can still select the image but, when pasted, it will just give a black box.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

   \begin{center} 
     \includegraphics[clip=true]{image.jpg}
   \end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make clear that this is (at most) an Adobe-specific solution. It does not prevent me copying the image from Okular, for example.

Comment: @KJO it worked five years back, at least in the reader I used at that time, which I am not sure of which one it was. Possibly the readers have changed since then. I am a chemist, so I really do not know. At least it worked for the OP at that time.

Comment: I do not know what AES or DRM is. I also do not know what a yellow duck has to do with this answer. If it is some kind of humor, I really do not get it. Down voting can be done without such paraphernalia

Comment: It was a useful solution for the OP five years back as evidenced by the check mark